# Building Windows server cluster hpc

Tags: cluster, windows, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-cluster, hpc

I'm trying to set up a Windows Server cluster with a head node and 2x compute nodes.

So far, i've managed to install : (thanks to this tutorial http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj884142.aspx)

-Head node with Windows Server 2012 Datacenter R2 and HPC 2012 R2

-2x Compute nodes with Windows Server 2012 Standard R2 and HPC 2012 R2

Also, I "added" my 2 nodes on my Head node via the Add node Wizard. And I see them marked as "OK" and "Online".

But when I try to submit and run a job, only the head node appears to work on the job, the compute nodes are not used.

Also, I have tried with a test program that make each node of the cluster say "Hello" written in C using MS MPI and only the head node appears to work. (Tools used Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate, MS MPI Library, compiled directly on the head node).

Answer (score 0):

After re-installing the cluster and run the same tests, they ran well both time.

Since I kept the former cluster settings I probably made a mistake the first time.